# Path validation error when pushing in react but works in postman/node directly

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, api, push

I am trying to push info from my sign up page . I can display it and even get an error 500 but i see a path validation even though i can directly post from postman to my db. Here is my signUp page . My model and route is written all the same so i dont understand

```
import React from "react";
import {
    MDBBtn,
    MDBContainer,
    MDBRow,
    MDBCol,
    MDBCard,
    MDBCardBody,
    MDBCardImage,
    MDBInput,
    MDBIcon,
    MDBCheckbox,
} from "mdb-react-ui-kit";
import Navbar from "./Navbar";
import Footer from "./Footer";
import {useState} from "react";

// const initFormData = Object({
//  //declaration de l'objet initiale pour recevoir les credentials
//  username: "",
//  email: "",
//  password: "",
//  // passwordCheck: "",ls
// });

const SignUpForm = () => {
    const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
const collectData = async () => {
  console.warn("warn" , username,email,password)
  let result = await fetch("http://localhost:8000/api/auth/register",{
    method: "post",
    body: JSON.stringify({username,email,password}),
    headers:{
      'Content-type':'shop/JSON'
    }
  });
  result = await result.json();
  console.warn(result);
}


    return (
        <>
            <Navbar />
            <MDBContainer fluid>
                <MDBCard className="text-black m-5" style={{borderRadius: "25px"}}>
                    <MDBCardBody>
                        <MDBRow>
                            <MDBCol
                                md="10"
                                lg="6"
                                className="order-2 order-lg-1 d-flex flex-column align-items-center"
                            >
                                <p className="text-center h1 fw-bold mb-5 mx-1 mx-md-4 mt-4">
                                    Sign up
                                </p>

                                <div className="d-flex flex-row align-items-center mb-4 ">
                                    <MDBIcon fas icon="user me-3" size="lg" />
                                    <MDBInput
                                        label="Votre Nom"
                                        id="form1"
                                        type="text"
                                        className="w-100"
                                        value={username}
                                        onChange={(e) => setUsername("username", e.target.value)}
                                    />
                                </div>
                                <div className="d-flex flex-row align-items-center mb-4 ">
                                    <MDBIcon fas icon="user me-3" size="lg" />
                                    <MDBInput
                                        label="Email"
                                        id="email"
                                        type="email"
                                        className="w-100"
                                        value={email}
                                        onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                                    />
                                </div>

            

                                <div className="d-flex flex-row align-items-center mb-4">
                                    <MDBIcon fas icon="lock me-3" size="lg" />
                                    <MDBInput
                                        label="Mot de passe"
                                        id="form3"
                                        type="password"
                                        name="password"
                                        value={password}
                                        onChange={(e) => setPassword("password" , e.target.value)}
                                    />
                                </div>

                            

                                <div className="mb-4">
                                    <MDBCheckbox
                                        name="flexCheck"
                                        value=""
                                        id="flexCheckDefault"
                                        label="Subscribe to our newsletter"
                                    />
                                </div>

                                <MDBBtn className="mb-4" size="lg" onClick={collectData()}>
                                    Register
                                </MDBBtn>
                            </MDBCol>

                            <MDBCol
                                md="10"
                                lg="6"
                                className="order-1 order-lg-2 d-flex align-items-center"
                            >
                                <MDBCardImage
                                    src="https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/img/Photos/new-templates/bootstrap-registration/draw1.webp"
                                    fluid
                                />
                            </MDBCol>
                        </MDBRow>
                    </MDBCardBody>
                </MDBCard>
            </MDBContainer>
            <Footer />
        </>
    );
};

export default SignUpForm;
```

i expected to be able to push but i get [image: here is the pb]

Comment: Try changing the method to `"POST"` in the **fetch()** call. You have it as lower case

Comment: Your url shouldn't have the localhost part. 
"/api/auth/register"